# Is there a word for "not cremated"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage

I am trying to come up with a term to represent human remains that have not been cremated; they will be buried in a casket. I tried *casketed*, but that's not actually word although it sounds good. *whole* just sounds like a strange and almost disrespectful word to use. Any ideas?

Edit: My specific usage is referring to a ceremony (burial at sea) that is different depending upon whether the person is cremated or not. For example, "only two of these locations allow **casketed** remains." The remains will not be buried in the traditional sense, because it is a burial at sea.

Comment: Everyone else just uses the *buried/cremated* distinction. Why doesn't that work for you?

Comment: Entombed, perhaps?

Comment: @FumbleFingers please see my edit

Comment: What's wrong with _casketed_? It seems entirely understandable.

Comment: But the cremated, the buried and the buried at sea all get 'casketed' (dreadful word) in the first instance, don't they?

Comment: Why not "uncremated"? Yes, it is a word.

Comment: How about *crème non brûlée*? (Sorry, couldn't resist.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with *buried*? The online MW [defines](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buried) it as:

> to put (a dead person or animal) in a grave

The word does not in any way imply cremation and a body that is *buried* will always be understood to be, well, not cremated. Otherwise, one refers to *ashes*.

---

Having seen your edit, I think you are backing yourself into a corner for no reason. Just change the formulation to:

> Caskets are only allowed in two of these locations.

or

> Cremation is required in all but two of these locations.

or

> Coffins are only allowed in two of these locations.

I see no reason to force an adjective into this.

Comment: In this case, the person is not buried yet. I will add more detail to the question.

Comment: @Ian in that case, it's a _corpse_, but see update.

Comment: Thank you, I guess a rephrasing makes more sense anyway.

Comment: Buried doesn't necessarily mean not cremated, since you can always bury an urn containing cremated remains.

Comment: @pacoverflow true but in that case, you will say that you buried the _urn_. In the absence of qualifiers, the simple _he was buried_ implies an entire body and a coffin.

Answer (score 3):

The expression used by the US EPA (Environmental Protection Agency) is *"[non-cremated remains](http://www.epa.gov/region2/water/oceans/burials.htm)"*, as is described on their site in terms of how a burial-at-sea must be prepared to meet local and federal laws.

Answer (score 0):

Try "embalmed".  It indicates preparation for burial that definitely does not involve cremation.

Another option might be "shrouded" if the body will be wrapped in preparation for burial.  Interestingly a quick search turned up a service that will rent you a yacht with crew and appropriate equipment for burial at sea. They mention "accepting prepared shroud (Strapped, weighted and identified from Funeral director).":

http://www.newenglandburialsatsea.com/burials-at-sea/